# Crawl webpage with loading image using Jsoup?

Tags: java, web-crawler, jsoup, connection-timeout

I'm building a web crawler for searching. Because I just need the title of article for indexing. I use Jsoup to connect URL destination.

```
Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(20000).execute();
```

But I got a problem **connection timeout**. I wonder if **timeout** occurs because of loading many images on that URL.

How can I get a webpage without loading images using Jsoup?

Comment: JSoup is an HTML crawler, so it doesn't download images. All it gets is `<img />` tags

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm that the page is not taking too long to load, try opening that URL in a browser and observe the time taken to load the page.

Jsoup has an option to wait infinitely by providing `(0)` in the timeout, like

```
Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(0).execute();
```

However for the timeout is better explained in the following [link](https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/issues/628).